# Installing on Android 4.x

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I just built an app with phonegap and it runs well just fine on android 7 but won’t run on android 4.x despite this

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

in config.xml.
Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

what version of the cordova android platform is being used?

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/ shows that support for API 10 was removed after cordova android 4.0